# Is there any method to determine a black box polynomial of real coefficients simply from inputs?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I came across this question which asked to determine a polynomial with positive integer coefficients for which the minimal substitutions required turned out to be 1.
I modified the problem by making it more general as in allowing the coefficients to be real. I have tried determining it by putting consecutive integer values from 0 until the successive difference reaches 0. This helps me to determine the degree of the polynomial and then creating a blueprint for the expressions of successive differences of the general polynomial of found degree, I can determine the unknown coefficients. This worked but someone showed me that if I get successive similar values, like getting 0 for consecutive integers, I can never know if the polynomial is just zero or just some polynomial of very high degree which vanishes at those particular integral inputs. I was also told that my method is similar to Newton's interpolation. Is there no method to determine the polynomial? Can there be no modifications/improvements to my method to solve this problem?
P.S.: The degree of the polynomial is of course unknown, and I find it by observing at how many levels the successive difference becomes zero. I need deg(P(x)) + 2 substitutions to reach that point.

Comment: Hello :) If you don't know the degree and you only know, that the coefficients are real, then it is impossible. But when you know, that the coefficients are rationals, then you put in $\pi$ and know all coefficients.

Comment: Your method for finding the degree won't (can't) work on a general black-box polynomial. The problem is that for any finite set of inputs and outputs, there are polynomials of arbitrarily high degree which have those outputs for those inputs. (eg if the inputs are $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$, you can always add $x^N(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dotsm(x-x_n)$ without changing the outputs) For example, I think your method would determine that if $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(2) = 4$, then $f$ has degree $2$? There are cubics like this - eg $x^2 + x(x-1)(x-2)$. Hence it's not possible to determine the polynomial in general.